# sqlite3 - GROUP BY query to sum almost all columns

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table called results, in which each row represents a ballot box (identified by the columns town code and ballot box code) and most of the columns represent different political parties, such that the value in each cell stands for number of votes a party received in a specific ballot box.

Some ballot boxes were split and appear twice (in two rows) with different data. I want to unite them to one row using the GROUP BY. In doing so, I need to sum all the columns that stand for the different parties.

The issue is that there are too many of those columns.

**Is there a way to refer to all of them using some keyword in the statement?**

For example, if I'd had only one column to sum, I would query:

```
SELECT town_code, ballot_code, SUM(party)
FROM results
GROUP BY town_code, ballot_code
```

Only that instead of the columns "party", I have too many columns to sum.

Comment: Too many? Too many political parties? Really? But anyway. Copy your select list out into a spreadsheet, then write a formula to wrap the `sum` function around the values you need summed, and to apply appropriate aliases to the columns.

Comment: Can you post sample of your data and desired result? In-text explanation is not too clear. Better to show than tell.

Comment: Eric Brandt - So in short you're saying there isn't a key word and I should type each and every column I want to sum?

Comment: @Ben, that's correct.